# trigger azure data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Is there any way to manually trigger a azure data factory pipeline? I would like to have this feature for a demo.

I know that we can suspend and resume a pipeline using power shell scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

1. create everything without pipeline active periods
2. When you want to run the demo update active periods to dates in the past
3. If you want to run again, update to another date in the past

Updating dates via powershell would look something like this

```
Set-AzureDataFactoryPipelineActivePeriod -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineName $PipelineName -StartDateTime $DateInPast -EndDateTime $DateOneDayLessInPast -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Force
```

Comment: By $DateOneDayLessInPast do you mean one day in the future from the $DateInPast or one day older than $DateInPast?

Answer (score 0):

try following url via postman:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelines/%7BpipelineName%7D/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01)

replace {} with your values

remember to add OAuth token. :)